# page refresh unsetting Ember controller property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise

If I do a manual page refresh or set a redirect like this

```
}).then(function() {
  document.location = "/";
}, function() {
```

in a function in my Ember app, an Ember controller property is becoming unset. I'm not sure if it matters *which* property is becoming unset, but in case it does, here's the code. In my application template, I check for whether a user is authenticated

```
    {{#if isAuthenticated}}
         blah blah
    {{else}}
        blah blah
    {{/if}}
```

The property is set in the AuthController

```
App.AuthController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    currentUser: null,
    isAuthenticated: Em.computed.notEmpty("currentUser.email"),
    login: function(route) {
      var me;
      me = this;
      return $.ajax({
        url: "/users/sign_in.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          "user[email]": route.currentModel.email,
          "user[password]": route.currentModel.password
        },
        success: function(data) {

          me.set('currentUser', data.user);
```

So, after I do a page refresh, my currentUser is (according to Ember) no longer showing as authenticated. However, on the (Ruby on Rails) server side the user is still authenticated. I put this code in the layout to check and after Ember thinks that I'm signed out (with a page refresh), my server code is still telling me I'm signed in (which in fact I am).

```
    <% if current_user %>
    there is a current user
    <% end %>
```

Can you explain why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your best is to set up is probably to make `isAuthenticated` a computed property that does an ajax **GET** to `/users/current` if `currentUser` is null. `/users/current` should return `{}` if the user is not authenticated, and the current user data if they are.

```
App.AuthController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  currentUser: null,
  isAuthenticated: function() {
    var currentUser = this.get('currentUser');
    if(Ember.isEmpty(currentUser)) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/users/current.json",
        async: true
      }).done( function( data ) {
        me.set('currentUser', data.user);
      });
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }.property('currentUser'),

});
```

Comment: If you can show me how to do that (make isAuthenticated computed), I'll accept your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a manual page refresh? This way you are starting the browser completely from scratch and therefore the Ember App initializes again and therefore the property currentUser is not set on your Controller.

Instead of doing this:

```
}).then(function() {
  document.location = "/";
}, function() {
```

I assume that you want to go to the start page of your app (since you want to go to "/"). **Instead you should use the Ember feature of transitioning between routes.** I do not know, where you execute the code above, but you can do this either from one of your controllers or in a route.

In a controller you could use [transitionToRoute](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute):

```
// index is a Route which is implicitly generated by Ember for you
this.transitionToRoute('index');
```

In a router you could use [transitionTo](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo):

```
this.transitionTo('index');
```

Comment: by manual page refresh he means clicking reload on the browser window. So this isn't going to help.

Comment: Oh yes. I have overseen the manual page refresh. I thought it would be just about programmatic manual refresh.

Comment: But can you explain why the property is getting unset? Ember is very brittle or is it my code?

Comment: i.e shouldn't I be able to do a manual page refresh without losing the property?

Comment: Yes this is the way it works. You do a manual refresh and the App starts from scratch and you lose that property. You are responsible for recreating the state. Either through deserialization of the URL or the approach Michael suggested.

Comment: @mavilein thanks, can you show the SO community how to do either/both of those approaches